# Why @State property is not set?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Local variable `d2` and `data` has the same type, but though d2 has two key value par, it is not getting assigned to `data`, why? Does `@State` makes it specific?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var data: [String: Any] = [String: Any]()
    @State var res: ValidationResult?

    init() {
        updateValue()
        return
    }
    
    func updateValue() {
        do {
            if let jsonURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "user", withExtension: "json") {
                let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL)
                guard let d2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Can not convert to d2")
                    return
                }
                data = d2 // <-------
```

Comment: Instead of a guard use do try catch there is likely a decoding error

Comment: Is it fixed if you manually set `data` to something, e.g. `["test": "123"]`? This would rule out the possibility of anything happening within the `do`, `if`, etc. PS: you may want to use `JSONDecoder` instead of `JSONSerialization` to ensure type-safety and ease of knowing whether a property/value exists.

Comment: can you add `print(String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8))` after `let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: jsonURL)` and show us what it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@State` starts it's work after the view appears so you need to remove it

```
var data = [String: Any]()
```

**Or** Do this structure instead

```
class Model:ObservableObject {
   @Published var data = "123"
   var input: [String: String] = ["name": "Janos", "address": "aaa"]
    init() {
        data = "456"
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
     @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(model.data)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI `@ObservedObject` is being used improperly to initialize you should use `@StateObject`